# Boosting Kentico smart search results relevance scope

Tags: lucene, kentico

I work with the Kentico smart search.
I want to boost smart search results relevance scope.
I read this [article](http://www.bizstream.com/blog/march-2017/boost-kentico-smart-search-results-relevance-score) that describes how to do it with a bool field.
According the article I have to create in a Kentico page type a bool column and then setup to the `Search condition` field of a smart search control this code:

```
columnname:(true)^3
```

If a required page contains this column and its value is `true` then this page relevance will be increased.
**It works.**

Now I'd like to do the same with an integer column. I want to keep in this column a coefficient that allows to increase the relevance.
I know that the Kentico uses the Apache Lucene search engine that I 've never use before. I found some examples and suggested that I have to setup to the `Search condition` field something like this:

```
columnname:(0)^0 columnname:(1)^1 columnname:(2)^2
```

I expect that the search results relevance scope will be increased according the value of the `columnname`.
**It doesn't work.**
Which syntax I have to use to achieve my goal if it's possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kentico by default stores integers in a special format. You therefore need to convert your integers to this format when building your query. Assuming you're building your query in code, you can do this with Kentico's helper method `SearchValueConverter.IntToString(id)` where `id` references your integer value. This code is untested, but you'll need something like:

```
string.Format(
  "columnname:({0})^0 columnname:({1})^1 columnname:({2})^2",
  SearchValueConverter.IntToString(id1),
  SearchValueConverter.IntToString(id2),
  SearchValueConverter.IntToString(id3))
```

Comment: Thank you Tom, but how to get an id?

Comment: The ID is the value of your integer field you're trying to boost on. In your example these are the values 0, 1 and 2 respectively. That Kentico method just converts the integer to the value it'll have in the index document. If you inspect your index with a tool like Luke you'll see the value 1 is changed to something like 10000000001.

Answer (score 0):

If understand correctly you want to give a boost depending on single column value
so each document contains boost value column (or their weight)

- If column value =0 -> give boost 0
- If column value =1 -> give boost 1
- If column value =2 -> give boost 2

Essentially each document contains its weight (boost) value right? Try something like this (assuming columnname is the column name in lucene index and your document type):

```
columnname:(int){%columname%}^{%columname%}
```

I am not sure about your architecture, but in this case you can simply create a sort (which is your boost column) column and sort results by this sort column?
They will be sorted by sort column, then by relevance inside

Comment: Thank you Shof. The problem was in a the type casting, as mentioned in Tom Troughton's comment. My Lucene syntax was correct but I have to cast column values to string explicitly or just use columns with the string (not integer) value type.